# Historical SQL Server query optimizer switching

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

In a previous but recent version of SQL Server, the query optimizer would switch algorithms when the database size passed a certain threshold. Does anyone recall this and can point me to documentation related to it, including any bugs?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Why would an optimizer change behavior depending on the size of a database? I could see that if a table changed dramatically or statistics caught up, but I don't see how the database size would be any factor.

Comment: You really need to be more descriptive

Comment: SQL Server does and has used statistics about *tables* for optimization purposes.  As far as I know, all versions of SQL Server have done this.  Are you confusing "database size" with "table size"?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have details, otherwise I'd find the answer myself. It may have been a switch from serial to parallel or vice versa. I encountered an incident in SharePoint 2007 that was traced to a bug in SQL Server related to query optimization and database size (index size?). It was fixed an a CU or SP that the customer had not installed.